# Does WaitOnAddress return when values match or when values differ?

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to use the `WaitOnAddress()` function to achieve read-write synchronization.

[According to MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitonaddress), `WaitOnAddress()` has the following declaration:

```c
BOOL WaitOnAddress(
  volatile VOID *Address,
  PVOID         CompareAddress,
  SIZE_T        AddressSize,
  DWORD         dwMilliseconds
);
```

and the following parameter definition:

> CompareAddress
>
> A pointer to the location of the previously observed value at `Address`. The function returns when the value at `Address` differs from the value at `CompareAddress`.

According to the definition, I should store and pass the current value of the watched address, so when the watch value changes, `WaitOnAddress()` will return. But this function does not work as I expected, so I wrote the following test code for `WaitOnAddress()` in Visual Studio (and also included linker library `Synchronization.lib`):

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>  // atoi 
#include <string.h> 

// include these two files after including winsock2.h
#include <process.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <synchapi.h>

void* threads(void* num) {
    int* number = (int*)num;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("number = %d\n", *number);
    }
    int catch = *number; // will be passed as CompareAddress
    WaitOnAddress((int*)num, &catch, sizeof(int), INFINITE);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("number2 = %d, %d\n", catch, *(int*)num);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    int int_list[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int_list[i] = i;
        _beginthread(threads, 0, (void*)&int_list[i]);
    }
    printf("hello\n");
    Sleep(1000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int_list[i] = 10 - i;
    }
    printf("changed\n");
    Sleep(1000);
    return 0;
}
```

In above code, `WaitOnAddress()` never returns even though the value it watches changes. But, if I change

```cpp
int catch = *number;
```

to:

```cpp
int catch = 10 - *number;
```

then `WaitOnAddress()` returns and the rest of the output is printed, as if it returns ONLY when the watched value matches the compared value.

But, I want to used the described behavior so my thread is released whenever the watched variable is changed.

Comment: How can you be sure that the threads have reached `WaitOnAddress` before the parent has changed all the values? Can you please show the output log?

Comment: From the documentation you linked to: "The function does not return until another thread in the same process signals that the value at Address has changed **by calling WakeByAddressSingle or WakeByAddressAll** or the timeout elapses, whichever comes first"

Comment: @kaylum thanks for reminding me. Upon another revision I found a false assumption I made to reach the wrong conclusion.

Comment: @RaymondChen indeed, thanks and,, my apology. How can I miss that sentence on every time reading that page?.. I should read manuals more carefully next time. BTW, may I ask what should I do to my question since it is not meaningful in stackoverflow? I fear deletion will be a disrespect for the messages you two posted yet I do not find a close button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitonaddress):

> **Parameters**
>
> **Address**
>
> The address on which to wait. If the value at Address differs from the
> value at CompareAddress, the function returns immediately. If the
> values are the same, the function does not return until another thread
> in the same process signals that the value at Address has changed by
> calling WakeByAddressSingle or WakeByAddressAll or the timeout
> elapses, whichever comes first.

Although you modify the value of the original array in the second loop, the `catch` and `num` are always the same when calling `WaitOnAddress` in the thread, so the `WaitOnAddress` function will not return.

You can try to modify it to:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>  // atoi 
#include <string.h> 

// include these two files after including winsock2.h
#include <process.h>
#include <Windows.h>

void* threads(void* num) {
    int* number = (int*)num;
    printf("number = %d\n", *number);
    int catch = *number; // will be passed as CompareAddress
    WaitOnAddress((int*)num, &catch, sizeof(int), INFINITE);
    printf("number2 = %d, %d\n", catch, *(int*)num);
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    int int_list[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int_list[i] = i;
        _beginthread(threads, 0, (void*)&int_list[i]);
    }
    printf("hello\n");
    Sleep(1000);
    printf("changed\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int_list[i] = 10 - i;
        WakeByAddressSingle(&int_list[i]);
    }
    Sleep(1000);
    return 0;
}
```

And it works for me:

[image]